# Java: How to force Annotation on Class?

Tags: java, annotations, abstract-class

I have one abstract Class:

```
public abstract class AbstractItem
```

and several concrete Classes:

```
public class ConcreteItem1 extends AbstractItem
public class ConcreteItem2 extends AbstractItem
public class ConcreteItem3 extends AbstractItem
```

also i have a custom Annotation:

```
@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation
```

How can i force my ConcreteItems to use the MyAnnotation?
Can i define that somehow in the AbstractItem-Class?

Comment: Do you mean that the ConcreteItems should *explicitly* have Author, or that they should *implicitly* have the same Author annotation as AbstractItem?

Comment: AbstractItem itself shouldn't have the Annotation at all. The Sub-Classes MUST have the Annotation.